# Basic SQL join query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a few tables:

event_type (`et`), event (`e`), event_booking (`eb`), person (`p`), person_address (`p`) and address_country (`ac`)

They are joined like so:

`et` <- `e` <- `eb` -> `p` -> `pa` -> `ac`

Every join has a one-to-one relationship, except the `eb` -> `p` link. A row in `eb` can have a `null` instead of an id from `p`.

I want to get all bookings, regardless of whether there's a corresponding row in `p`.

So, a simple left join.

but which would be better? (or is there a better way?)

`et J e J eb LJ p LJ pa LJ ac` (I'm assuming this would be treated identically to `ac J pa J p RJ eb RJ e RJ et`?)

or

`et J e J eb LJ (p J pa J ac)` (i.e. left join a sub-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the following syntax - which somehow corresponds to your second scenario

```
select
    *
from 
    eb
    inner join e on eb.eId = e.eId
    inner join et on e.etId = et.etId
    left join p
           inner join pa on p.paId = pa.paId
           inner join ac on pa.acId = ac.acId
        on eb.pId = p.pId
```

I am not sure about the performance implications but I would not be surprised if both scenarios generated the same query plan

Comment: Thanks Kristof, I think that'll be ideal. Strange syntax I've not really used before!

Answer (score 1):

Just test your queries using EXPLAIN, it will show if and how keys are used.